# Matlab bad performance under Jenkins

Tags: windows, bash, matlab, jenkins

I have a Jenkins script execution step which processes out-data with Matlab to perform evaluation of test results.

When running the script from command prompt it starts up and exits quite fast but when executing the same script with the same arguments from Jenkins it performs extremely por. I get the Matlab welcome message in the "prompt only" window that appears but nothing else within the timeout of 2 hours that I have set for the job.

Have disabled the Jenkins Windows service on node and are running the node-process from desktop but no difference:

```
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe -jar c:\j-mpc\slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://<server>/slave-agent.jnlp -secret <xxxxx>
```

Also tried to increase the memory for the node process in but no change:

```
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe -Xmx2048m
```

When killing the process-tree starting with bash it indicates that it is inherited from java.exe-sh.exe tree (Pocess Explorer window) but there is a missing PID in between:

```
java.exe (<0.01%, 1 420 000K) 
  sh.exe (<0.01%, 2 140K)
bash.exe (<0.01%, 2 580K)
  bash.exe (     , 2 580K)
    python.exe (     , 6 044K)
      python.exe (     , 4 800K)
        matlab.exe (     , 1 844K)
          MATLAB.exe (<0.01%, 167 324K)
```

Is there a hidden limitation in child processes that limits the memory or process usage when called from Jenkins, in other jobs I don't see the same limitations. Memory allocation for Matlab is very slow (from start to reasonable size >100M takes about a minute)

(Have a screen dump from Process Explorer but I am not allowed to upload)

**EDIT**

I have also tried to limit the call to a single windows command line from Jenkins with the same result (suspected that the deep call stack was to blame for it) but same result.

```
matlab.exe -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -logfile "log_file.txt" -r "try script_file ;catch err; disp(err.message); end ; exit"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by setting the **LM_LICENSE_FILE** environment variable in Jenkins node setup.
(found a [thread about slow startup](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93345-why-does-matlab-take-so-long-to-start-if-i-am-disconnected-from-the-network))

Apparently the shell environment started by Jenkins does not completely comply with the one started from explorer.